# Jquery append to PRE tag without quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

JS fiddle example at http://jsfiddle.net/wR9P9/1/

In the HTML code of the example, I have two PRE tags. One defined as id=good which already has data populated. The 2nd PRE tag has id=bad. This tag does not have data defined, instead it is dynamically populated, for now in the javascript using append.

```
 var testY = [0,1,2,3]
var testX = [0,1,2,3]
var testValue = [5,10,15,20,2,4,6,8,3,6,9,12,4,8,12,16]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $.each(testY, function(k,v) {
            $.each(testX, function(k2,v2) {
                $.each(testValue, function(k3,v3) {
                     $("#bad").append(v + "," + v2 + "," + v3);  
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In line 197 of the javascript code, i can toggle between the good and bad pre tag ids to see the difference.

My problem is that when I use append, it is appending each element with double quotes that is causing my chart to break.

How can I append to the PRE tag without it including double quotes?

0,0,25 instead of "0,0,25"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` and `$()` do exactly the same thing; you only need one or the other.

Comment: Also I don't see any quotes at all. When I make the "bad" element visible, there are no quotes.

Comment: your right, i dont see any quotes either when unhiding the elements but they appear in when debugging thru the console. The only difference I see between bad and good elements are the double quotes

Comment: @MichoRizo that's just the way the console works; there are no quote characters in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chart gets created before you fill your pre-tag with data, because your data-creation is within (multiple) `$(document).ready(function() { .. }) / $(function() { .. })`. Solving that (commented out within the jsFiddle) will create a filled chart.

Besides that, you miss a new-line-character after your data, I've also added that one.

http://jsfiddle.net/wR9P9/5/

Comment: I agree that the redundant "ready" setup is wrong, but I still don't see any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is what you need and this one too its all about playing with single and double quotes
wrap everything in single quotes and add double inside it
that should do it.
EXAMPLE:
    `$("#bad").append('"' + v + ',' + v2 + ',' + v3 + '"');`

Comment: He does not want quotes.